# Accessing element height in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

I am trying to write a native script app which retrieves the rendered height of the `bottle` view/element in my xml. I have tried the following code, but unfortunately, I get an error (shown below). Any guidance would be much appreciated.

JS:

```
var viewModule = require("ui/core/view");
var page;

exports.fabTap = function (args) {
      page = args.object;
      var bottle = page.getViewById("bottle");
      console.log("Height: " + bottle.height);
  }
```

XML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:FAB="nativescript-floatingactionbutton" actionBarHidden="true" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <GridLayout columns="*, *, *, *" rows="15*, 5*, 20*, 5*, 5*, 5*, 5*, 20*, 20*" width="100%" height="100%" style.backgroundColor="white" >
    <Image src="res://logo" row="0" col="1" colSpan="2" stretch ="aspectFit" class="logo"/>
    <Image id="bottle" src="res://bottle_outline" row="2" col="0" rowSpan="6" colSpan="2" stretch="aspectFit"/>
  </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

> Cannot read property 'height' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the `fabTap` handler, `args.object` is not the page but the FAB widget itself. So when you call `getViewById` it searches the view hierarchy of the FAB widget, and there is no bottle there :) You should change your code as follows:

```
var viewModule = require("ui/core/view");
var page;
exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
   page = args.object;
}
exports.fabTap = function (args) {
   var bottle = page.getViewById("bottle");
   console.log("Height: " + bottle.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, that seems to have solved the undefined issue. But I now get `Height: NaN` printing to the log, why might this be?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Seems `height` only returns if you set the property and not return the actual one. Try printing `bottle.getMeasuredHeight()` and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

To get the calculated size of the view, not what you declared in the styles:

```js
const viewModule = require("ui/core/view");
let page;

exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
   page = args.object;
}

exports.fabTap = function (args) {
   const bottle = page.getViewById("bottle");
   console.log("Height: " + bottle.getActualSize().height);
}
```